# How to print the last column from a specific row?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've got `datafile` file which more or less looks something like this:

```
*** some text ***
Results
1     50
2    -75
3     80
*** some text ***
```

What I'd like to do is:

1. Find the line that contains the string "Results".
2. List those three results but only the last column is significant.
3. Show only the positive ones.

I was trying to solve my problem with `awk` command which for each result looks like this:

```
res1=$(awk '/Results/{nr[NR+1]}; NR in nr' datafile | awk '{print $NF}')
```

I hoped to get the first positive results by:

```
If [ $res1 -gt 0 ]; then
echo "$res1"
fi
```

But instead of the expected result I've got the error `Integer expression expected`. So it leads to a conclusion that the variable `res1` isn't a numeric value. Any idea how to define it properly?

Comment: when `res1="50\n-75\n80"`, the if statement won't understand. Try everything in one awk call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$ awk '$0 == "Results" { f = 3; next } f && f-- && $NF > 0 { print $NF }' input
50
80
```

Basically the variable `f` is set to 3 when the line `Results` is passed.

Then the last column from the next lines are printed as long as `f > 0` and `$NF > 0` `$NF` is the last column.